# Why is ASP.NET WEB API not returning 200 Ok as my response in ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net web api that checks if a user is logged in.When i debug i get 200 OK response from the API controller but when i inspect in fiddler I get two 200 Ok response. One is empty without the object its is suppose to return and the other response contain the response with the object.

Controller code

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/BTS_Admin/Login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage AdminLogin(Admin admin)
    {
        Admin response = admin.LoginCheck();
        if (response != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Login Failed");
        }
    }
```

Also when I am suppose to get success response from ajax i get the response returned in the error section of the ajax call

Ajax call code

```
                $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:61468/api/BTS_Admin/Login',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: JSON,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Email: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                    Password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                }),
                success: function (response) {
                    //localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token);
                    //localStorage.setItem('userName', response.userName);
                    window.location.href = "Data.html";

                 },
                 error: function (jqXHR) {
                    $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('#divError').show('fade');

                }

            });
```

**Note:** This is where i get the response

```
                    error: function (jqXHR) {
                    $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('#divError').show('fade');
```

Comment: What response  do you get instead? Did you try to debug the code and check if server code is working fine?

Comment: The server code is returning 200 Ok status when I inspected it on fiddler. But I am getting two response fro fiddler. One with 200 Ok response and my object and the other with 200 Ok response without an object.

Comment: `btnLogin` is a normal button or submit button ?

Comment: Maybe you use submit button and after click on it, your Ajax code is sending data to server and your page is refreshing at the same time. This can be a cause of this problem. Try then use only sending data by form and don't use Ajax.

Comment: Have a look at the Request Method on the request that has no object - I expect it is an `OPTIONS` request, running as part of the CORS validation process.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya btnLogin is a normal button

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes it is an OPTIONS request. Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you see an error in the console similar to `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:61468/api/BTS_Admin/Login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`?

Comment: Please include what you're getting with Fiddler.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I have enabled CORS in my webapi.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/BTS_Admin/Login")]
public HttpResponseMessage AdminLogin(Admin admin)
{
    Admin response = admin.LoginCheck();
    if (response != null)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
    }
    else
    {
        //ajax get error from here, because you set 404 error (Not found.)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Login Failed");
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/BTS_Admin/Login")]
public IHttpActionResult AdminLogin(Admin admin)
{
    Admin response = admin.LoginCheck();
    return Ok(response);
}
```

And in ajax request check returned value:

```
            $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:61468/api/BTS_Admin/Login',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: JSON,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Email: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                Password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
            }),
            success: function (response) {
                if(response){
                //Do somethig
                  window.location.href = "Data.html";
                }else{
                    $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('#divError').show('fade');               
                }
             },
             error: function (jqXHR) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

When you in controller set response status code not 200OK, ajax think that this is a error, so error callback fire up.

Comment: I tried your solution but i am still getting the same error

Comment: Thanks Guys I just got the thing working. I changed the data-Type from JSON to 'json' .

Comment: dataType:json , text .. its mean return type of data from server.